# file.delete() not deleting file from sdcard in Android programatically

Tags: android, file, delete-file

I am trying to delete a file from sdcard using `delete` method but after several attempts, the file still exists in the sdcard. Tried many SO questions and solutions but failing the attempts.

```
public void deleteFile(String filepath) throws IOException 
{
    
    File file = new File(filepath);
    Log.d(TAG,filepath);
    try {
        file.delete();
        if (file.exists()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "file exists 1");
            file.getCanonicalFile().delete();
            if (file.exists()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "file exists 2");
                getApplicationContext().deleteFile(file.getName());
                if(file.exists()){
                    Log.d(TAG, "file exists 3");
                    file.getAbsoluteFile().delete();
                }
            }
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "File deleted");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Exception");
    }
}
```

Output in Logcat :

```
> /storage/emulated/0/important.txt
> file exists 1
> file exists 2
> file exists 3
> File deleted
```

Despite no error or exception, the file still is present inside `sdcard` (or to be specific `/storage/emulated/0/`.

What am I missing ?

I have added the required permissions :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: What method are you using to verify that the file was deleted? When you're using the Android Studio Device File Explorer, you may have to "Synchronize" after the `delete()` method call

Comment: I am going into `adb shell` and traversing to `/storage/emulated/0/`. There I still see `important.txt` file.

Comment: Instead of repeatedly using `file.exists()` it will be useful to check the return value from each `delete()` call, since each of the calls, including `deleteFile()` returns true if and only if the file was successfully deleted. Right now your code simply falls through to the "File deleted" Log. If you use the `Files.delete(filePath)` method it provides more details if there was an error while deleting the file (Added in Java 7 but in Android this requires Android O or higher). In general using the `Files` class is better than using the `File` class.

Answer (score 1):

While trying to find solution, I learned that `READ/WRITE` permissions come under protection level: `dangerous`

If the permission level is dangerous and if the Android version is 6 or above, then we need to explicitly ask for permission at runtime, despite mentioning in AndroidManifest.

I added runtime permissions inside `onCreate()` of MainActivity, as mentioned below and then after a simple `file.delete()` was enough to delete the file.

```
if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 0);
        }
if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 0);
        }
```