# Xamarin: How to delete files using CrossFilePicker Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I am  using the following code to pick a file using CrossFilePicker in Xamarin forms. Goal is to delete the selected file in Xamarin.Android project, file still intact after running the command.

```
            FileData filedata = await CrossFilePicker.Current.PickFile();
            Android.Net.Uri uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(filedata.FilePath);

            Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(uri.Path);
            File.Delete(file.AbsolutePath);
            await DisplayAlert("✅", file.AbsolutePath, "Okay");
```

When using the DisplayAlert to check the filepath, I saw the below path, but file doesn't delete!!

```
          /storage/emulated/0/documents/SalesRecords.db3
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68182885/file-delete-not-deleting-file-from-sdcard-in-android-programatically

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use [Essentials.FilePicker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/file-picker?context=xamarin%2Fandroid&tabs=android), it allows you to pick file with code like:

```
async Task<FileResult> PickAndShow(PickOptions options)
{
    try
    {
        var result = await FilePicker.PickAsync(options);
        if (result != null)
        {
            Text = $"File Name: {result.FileName}";
            if (result.FileName.EndsWith("jpg", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
                result.FileName.EndsWith("png", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                var stream = await result.OpenReadAsync();
                Image = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);
            }
        }
        
        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // The user canceled or something went wrong
    }
    
    return null;
}
```

And once you get the result you can delete the file like:

```
    FileResult file= await PickAndShow(PickOptions.Default);
    File.Delete(file.FullPath);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the support, finally solve it out by including permission to manage file